# Sorting ellipses by resemblance to a circle

Tags: opencv

So I need to extract ellipses that are closest to being circles using OpenCV and Java since I have lot of false ellipses found. I have found the ellipses with color extraction and

```
Imgproc.fitEllipse(thisContour2f);
```

Current idea is to check all ellipse points and calculate widths from center. Those ellipses whose width variance in value is the smallest are closest to a circle in that image. Any better ideas?

I have also tried using Hough Circle but this does not detect anything.

Comment: So your ellipses are given as sets of points?

Comment: No I was hoping to extract ellipse points from `RotatedRect` but found it's not that easy. So currently I take `rotatedRect.boundingRect();` and sort them by `Math.abs(height-width);` so I get the rects that are closest to a square thus it's `RotatedRect` is closest to a circle.

Comment: To my surprise it gives quite accurate results.

Comment: If you have an ellipse which is much longer than wide, and it's rotated by 45°, then its axis-aligned bounding box is a square. So I don't think that works in general. Or the bounding boxes aren't axis aligned?

Comment: Yes, that might break some things.

Comment: please beware that ellipse fitting is very different from ellipse detection! So if you aren't certain that  `thisContour2f` is an ellipse at all, your whole approach might create problems if your contours are something different than ellipses.

Comment: @cfh : according to the documentaiton the function [fitEllipse](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaf259efaad93098103d6c27b9e4900ffa&gsc.tab=0) "returns the rotated rectangle in which the ellipse is inscribed.".